# How can I build on ubuntu something that was meant for FreeBSD?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, makefile, freebsd

I'm trying to build this: https://github.com/hselasky/hpsat_generate
this is their makefile:

```
PROG_CXX=hpsat_generate
PREFIX?=/usr/local
MAN=
SRCS=   hpsat_generate.cpp
BINDIR?=${PREFIX}/bin

.if defined(HAVE_DEBUG)
CFLAGS+= -g -O0
.endif

CFLAGS+= -I${PREFIX}/include
LDFLAGS+= -L${PREFIX}/lib -lgmp -lgmpxx

.include <bsd.prog.mk>
```

using just `make .` results in

```
Makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

so after some searching I found that I need to use FreeBSD make, so I tried:
`bmake . hpsat_generate`
which complains that [mergesort](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mergesort&sektion=3) is not declared, which is a FreeBSD function so I can only assume it doesn't really includes it.

I tried finding a way to make it run but I'm out of ideas..

Comment: `mergesort` is in the `libbsd` libs which should be available for Ubuntu. Install it and ensure it's linked against it.

Comment: Given that the entire project consists of a grand total of a single `.cpp` file: forget the makefile, and simply execute `g++` yourself. All that the BSD makefile will do is execute `g++ -o hpsat_generate hpsat_generate.cpp`. Of course, there's no guarantee that the code will actually compile, for BSD-related reasons, but that's all that this makefile appears to do, why torture yourself trying to get bsd make to work?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik C++ building is my pet peeve and I usually get lost, for anyone else wondering this is the final command: `g++ -o sat sat.cpp -lgmp  -lgmpxx -l:libbsd.a`

Answer (score 1):

The `Makefile` requires some changes for Linux (and NetBSD). The `bsd.prog.mk` implementation that comes with `bmake` on Linux is slightly off, and requires a workaround to link the program correctly, also, on Linux you need `libbsd`:

These issues are fixed by [PR #1](https://github.com/hselasky/hpsat_generate/pull/1).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running the makefile just execute this:

`g++ -o sat sat.cpp -lgmp  -lgmpxx -l:libbsd.a`

you may need to install the gmp and libbsd libraries